# Where is trace_regmap_async_write_start() defined?

Tags: linux

I am trying to port some codec code/files back to linux 3.2 and there's a function trace_regmap_async_write_start() there that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

See here: [https://gitorious.org/ti-codecs/ti-codecs/source/2a6df0d6bb1c270aba57018fad5d3cde221e4d4f:drivers/base/regmap/regmap.c](https://gitorious.org/ti-codecs/ti-codecs/source/2a6df0d6bb1c270aba57018fad5d3cde221e4d4f%3adrivers/base/regmap/regmap.c)

I've tried to search for it but can only see references to where it's called, not defined or declared. I'm wondering whether it might be some kind of macro?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From file `linux/include/trace/events/regmap.h`, you can see:

```
195 DEFINE_EVENT(regmap_block, regmap_async_write_start,                            
196                                                                                 
197     TP_PROTO(struct device *dev, unsigned int reg, int count),                  
198                                                                                 
199     TP_ARGS(dev, reg, count)                                                    
200 );
```

According to [this](http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-regmap-async-Add-tracepoints-for-async-I-O-td605341.html), it seem that it add tracepoints when we start async I/O.

Comment: Thank you! as it turned out there were another couple of missing definitions in same place.